# How do I combine a list of objects where each object has duplicate category and unique article?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, javascript-objects

I would like to combine all the `article` objects in this dataset:

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: {
      id: 1,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 1,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'bbb',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 2,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'ccc',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 3,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'ddd',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 3,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'eee',
    },
  },
]
```

Underneath the same `category` if the `category.id` matches. Like so:

```js
[
  {
    category: {
      id: 1,
    },
    articles: [
      {
        title: 'aaa',
      },
      {
        title: 'bbb',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 2,
    },
    articles: [
      {
        title: 'ccc',
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 3,
    },
    articles: [
      {
        title: 'ddd',
      },
      {
        title: 'eee'
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Any ideas? Happy to use Lodash something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function. Inside reduce call back function use `findIndex` to check if the accumulator array have an object with `id` same as id of the current object under iteration. If it is same then update the articles array else create a new object with required key and push it to the accumulator array

```js
const data = [{
    category: {
      id: 1,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 1,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'bbb',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 2,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'ccc',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 3,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'ddd',
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: 3,
    },
    article: {
      title: 'eee',
    },
  }
]


let newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIdIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.category.id === curr.category.id
  });

  if (findIdIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({
      category: {
        id: curr['category']['id']
      },
      articles: [{
        title: curr.article.title
      }]
    })


  } else {
    acc[findIdIndex].articles.push({
      title: curr.article.title
    })

  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much @brk !